# Sonar - Can we use for OSB/BPEL code review?

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to sonar,just heard about this tool.

Can we use this tool to perform code review for FMW(Fusion Middleware) -OSB(Oracle Service Bus)/BPEL project ?
If so can anyone give some inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

The official plugin-List : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Plugin+Library/ does not mention support for your tools.

But sonar can be extended with custom plugins, so you may be able to write your own plugins to provide metrics for your tools.

Answer (score 0):

What level of review you want to cover? It is really easy to make your own review tool for BPEL. All BPEL resources are XML files. For example if you want to check for naming convetion of BPEL activities, you can define a simple XPath based rule.
Ex:

```
//sequence/@name ~= "^sequence.*".
```

A Java program can use the above XPath to pull-out all sequence names from the xxxx.bpel file and compare it against a regular expression. Similar rules can be created for checking WSDL usage, partner links, end-point addresses, usage of Error handling etc.

Comment: which version of xpath/SonarQube supports operator `~=`?